# A density result in $W^{1,p} (\mathbb{R}^n) \cap C^{1}(\mathbb{R}^n)$

Tags: sobolev-spaces, approximation-theory

is the following result valid?:

If $ u \in W^{1,p} (\mathbb{R}^n) \cap  C^{1}(\mathbb{R}^n)$, then $\forall  \epsilon > 0 ~ \exists f \in C_{c}^{\infty}$ s.t. $\|u-f\|_{W^{1,p}(\mathbb{R}^n)} < \epsilon$

I can't find it anywhere. I tried to look on Evans, partial differential equation, and Adams, Fournier, Sobolev spaces.
Thank you

Comment: Luckily I found the answer on Brezis, Functional Analysis, Sobolev Spaces and Partial Differential Equations, theorem 8.7 and remark 13. I'll leave it here if someone else have the same question.

Comment: I was just looking through the book by Brezis. The theorem you reference deals with the case $n=1$ (as does all of chapter 8 in that book). For general $n$, you want Theorem 9.2.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Take a function $\varphi_n\in C^\infty_c(\mathbb{R}^n)$ with $0\le\varphi_n\le1$, $\varphi_n=1$ in $B(0,n)$ and $\varphi_n=0$ outside $B(0,n+1)$, and (this is important) $\Vert \nabla\varphi_n\Vert_\infty\le C$ for all $n$. Then $f_n=u\varphi_n$ converges in $W^{1,p}$ to $u$. Indeed, $f_n\to u$ pointwise and
$\vert f_n\vert\le \vert u\vert$ and so by the Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem $f_n\to u$ in $L^p$. On the other hand,
$$\nabla f_n= \varphi_n \nabla u+u\nabla \varphi_n$$ and so 
$\nabla f_n\to \nabla u$ pointwise and
$$\vert \nabla f_n\vert \le \vert \nabla u\vert +C\vert u\vert $$and so again  by the Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem we have that $\nabla f_n\to \nabla u$ in $L^p$.